# Issue with windows 10 audio driver

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers

I am unable to find the cause/fix of the issue which is why I am asking here. Recently in Windows 10, there is a feature in audio control which allows us to control audio for different applications along with control at the device end as well. Although the problem that I am facing is that even though the device audio is zero, the application can still play audio on it.

Screenshot for the same:

---

[image]

---

In the image even when audio is zero, you can see green bar against the device indicating the sound is still working. This is very problematic as volume reduction using "volume keys" and even the device mute does not work. the I can confirm that the setting of "Allow application to take specific control of the device" in Advanced properties of the device is disabled and all sound effects are disabled.

Please help to guide what can be done to fix this problem. I am thinking this might be some misconfiguration at my end. Any leads in this would be appreciated.

Comment: Make and model of sound device? There may be a newer driver for it.

Answer (score 0):

When I check on google conexant isst, [this](https://betanews.com/2021/01/25/microsoft-windows-10-conexant-isst-audio-driver-problems-workaround/) hit my face. Did you check this driver update?